# print to the Ghidra console from a Ghidra java plugin

Tags: plugins, ghidra

In ghidra script you can just println("to the console");

However I need to print to the ghidra console from a ghidra plugin (a real jar plugin, not a script).

I found that I can get an instance of ConsoleService via:

```
 ConsoleService consoleService = pluginTool.getService(ConsoleService.class);
 consoleService.print("hello");
```

my plugin looks like the following:

```
public class MyPlugin extends AbstractAnalyzer {
    public MyPlugin() {
        setSupportsOneTimeAnalysis(true);
    }
}
```

How do I get an instance of a PluginTool so that I could get the ConsoleService?

Answer (score 1):

Every Ghidra plugin that is loaded in a tool should have the tool available as field called `tool`, see https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/framework/plugintool/Plugin.html#tool

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but better late than never.

Analyzers aren't Plugins.

Plugins, and the PluginTool they live in, are a GUI concept.  Analyzers are decoupled from the GUI and need to work independently of that.  (think headless analyzer)

Analyzers can use (`ghidra.util.`)`Msg.info()`, `Msg.warn()`, `Msg.error()` to log messages to ghidra's log.  Also, the `Analyzer.added()` method has a `MessageLog` param that you can use to alert the user about issues that during analysis.